# css text-decoration:none won't remove text underline

Tags: css, text-decorations

I have some text which is underlined but text-decoration:none won't remove text underline.

You can see that on the landing page of my website [here]<michelgrolet.fr>. You will find it easily : it's the only underlined text on the landing page.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: i think you forgot your closing quotation mark

Comment: Anchor (a) tags have their own styling applied by the browsers so remember to set the text decoration for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your Existing Code In `style.css` On 182th Line.

```
.game-link h5, .game-link p {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-decoration-color: var(--white-l);
}
```

**To ->>**

```
.game-link h5, .game-link p {
    text-decoration: inherit;
    text-decoration-color: var(--white-l);
}
```

## OR

Add Css -

```
a.game-link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding :

> text-decoration: none!important;